# Add cell to tableview with animation is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I`ve been stocked in this for days and its driving me crazy, the problem is that I want to add a cell to my tableview with a animation but when returning from the textfield (this is when I want the animation to happen) it crashes, obviously something is wrong with my code, so I need your help!! thanks!

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"]];
    if(!self.tasks)
    {
        self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"] ;


    [self.tableview beginUpdates];

    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(self.tasks.count - 1) inSection:0];
[self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tableview endUpdates];

 }
```

Somebody told me that before calling endUpdates I need to make sure that my model is updated so that the value returned from `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` will be correct but honestly I dont know how to do that

Here is the crash log:
[image]

And here is the datasource of the table:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{  
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tasks.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TaskCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.taskTitle.text = (self.tasks)[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post details about the crash. What is the full error message and which line of code crashes?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your UITableViewDataSource it's hard to tell, but it looks like you can resolve your problem by moving the [self.tasks addObject...] so that it's also bracketed by the beginUpdates/endUpdates.  Those two calls should bracket the all of the operations necessary to add the item (adding it to the data set and also adding it to the tableview)

Comment: Also, more or less obviously, you'll need to move the userDefaults setObject to after the begin/end block.

Comment: @David - neither of those are valid points. There is no need to move any of the lines of code.

Comment: @maddy If his tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: is return self.tasks.count which would be the normal model then changes to self.tasks needs to happen inside the begin/end block.

Comment: Also, as it stands, assuming tasks starts empty, the first call will add row 1, not row 0.  Moving the addObject call will fix that as well since self.tasks.count will not yet have changed.

Comment: I add the crash log and the data source so you can see it if it helps, thanks!

Comment: @David - There is NO requirement for the update of the data model to be after the call to `beginUpdates`. In fact, in this case, the calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` are pointless since there is only a single call to update the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an off-by-one error here.

By setting the row to `self.tasks.count` you are actually increasing it too much. I assume you are wanting to add it to the end, therefore just subtract one.

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(self.tasks.count - 1) 
                                               inSection:0];
```

Also, you want to make sure that in `numberOfRowsInSection:` you return the length of your array, so don't use `self.TasksArray.count` use `self.tasks.count`. Same with your cell: `self.tasks[indexPath.row]`

Also, as a side note, make sure to synchronize your changes to `userDefaults` or else it won't propagate.

### Update - improve `self.tasks`

Instead of re-initializing `self.tasks` each time you add an item, initialize it as a mutable array in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                initWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"]];
```

Then when you create a new task all you need to do is add it:

```
[self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
[userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

No need to check if it is created or not. See docs for [synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize).

Comment: It worked the first time I test it but now It crashes with a similar Log that the first one: NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'.

Comment: And you updated all of your variables to use the same one? If so, could you update your code in your question so I can see if there is anything thing else that stands out. You might also try doing an `NSLog` after you add the object and see how many objects are there and then do one in `numberOfRowsInSection:` to make sure it matches up as expected.

Comment: OK I update it, when I run the app for the 1st time it works great but if I relaunch the entries to task are deleted and when I try to add something in the textfield It crashes :( I try moving the initialisation of tasks to the viewdidload but didnt work thanks

Comment: Are you synchronize your changes in the user default? How are you initializing your `self.tasks` in the beginning?

Comment: Yes I synchronize before and after tableview endUpdates, I didnt put it on the question, and tes I initialise self.tasks in viewdidload:

Comment: self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.userdefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"]];
    if(!self.tasks)
    {
        self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

Comment: If you do initalize that in `viewDidLoad` then you don't need to do that work in `textFieldShouldReturn:`. If you are getting the same crash, do the `NSLog` like I suggested and make sure that your count is correct in both spots.

Comment: I did the nslog and always is nil, even if I add something in the textfield, but in other nslog that I have in textfieldshouldreturn it sends the number of objects in self.tasks: NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count); and it continue crashing in 2nd launches, only works in the first launch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49667/discussion-between-ryanjm-and-user3290977)